# My program returns the error "vector subscript out of range."

Tags: c++

I'm not sure which vector is causing the error or where the issue is coming from. I'm trying to input names and birthdates from a file and set them equal to a part in the vector. The file is:

```
Mark,12/21/1992
Jay,9/29/1974
Amy Lynn,3/17/2010
Bill,12/18/1985
Julie,7/10/1980
Debbie,5/21/1976
Paul,1/3/2001
Ian,2/29/1980
Josh,10/31/2003
Karen,8/24/2011
```

I am not even sure if my code accomplishes this because of the error. I tried reading more into stringstream but I did not understand how to correctly implement it. The date class mentioned can be provided if necessary, but it is quite long. Any input on improving the program and why the issue is happening is greatly appreciated. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "c://cpp/classes/Date.cpp"
using namespace std;

struct person {
    vector<string> name; // One name string vector
    vector<Date> birthdate; // One birthdate vector
    vector<Date> birthday; // birthday vector
};

int main() {
    string input, input2; // Two string inputs
    const int PEOPLE_NUM = 10; // Amount of people

    vector<person> People(PEOPLE_NUM); // Define vector called People with 10 positions
    string test;
    ifstream inputFile("C:/Users/Taaha/Documents/CMSC226/Project 3/Names.txt", ios::in);
    for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE_NUM; i++) {
        getline(inputFile, input, ','); // input the line, stop when a comma
        People[i].name[i] = input; // Add input into the vector 
        getline(inputFile, input2, ',');
        People[i].birthdate[i] = input2;
        cout << i;
    }
    inputFile.close(); // close file

    Date birthday;
    for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE_NUM; i++) {
        Date birthday(People[i].birthday[i].getDay(), People[i].birthday[i].getMonth(), Date().getYear());
        People[i].birthday[i] = birthday;
    } // Not finished yet, but turns birthdate into birthday
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks again :]

Comment: Off topic: Rather than having a structure of `vector`s, consider instead a `vector` of structures. Very likely simplify your code.

Comment: You're accessing indexes (aka `vector.name[i]`) that don't exist yet. You have to use `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` to create slots for that things you want to put in the vector. Also, I'm almost certain you are misusing vector in `struct person`. Most likely you do not want vectors in `person` unless people have suddenly started having more than one birthday.

Comment: Ah okay, and do you think the issue I get is coming from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `People[i].name[i] = input;` in the for loop, `People[i].name` is still a empty vector, call `operator[]` on it will be UB. You might `resize` them in advance, or use `push_back`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE_NUM; i++) {
    getline(inputFile, input, ',');
    People[i].name[i] = input;        // People[i].name is still empty here 
    getline(inputFile, input2, ',');
    People[i].birthdate[i] = input2;  // People[i].birthdate is still empty here
    cout << i;
}
```

You might use `push_back`, such as,

```
for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE_NUM; i++) {
    getline(inputFile, input, ',');
    People[i].name.push_back(input); 
    //            ~~~~~~~~~~
    getline(inputFile, input2, ',');
    People[i].birthdate.push_back(input2);
    //                 ~~~~~~~~~~
    cout << i;
}
```

And it's same for another for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE_NUM; i++) {
    Date birthday(People[i].birthdate[i].getDay(), People[i].birthdate[i].getMonth(), Date().getYear());  // typo of birthdate?
    //                      ~~~~~~~~~                        ~~~~~~~~~
    People[i].birthday.push_back(birthday);
    //                 ~~~~~~~~~~
} // Not finished yet, but turns birthdate into birthday
```

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately I am still receiving the error (Expression: vector subscript out of range) at line 1232. I am also getting the error "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" && 0 at line 1233.

Comment: Please give me one moment to revise my code, thanks.

Comment: @Cool What's the content of line 1232?

Comment: This is line 1232 of the directory it says: #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
  if (size() <= _Pos)
   { // report error
   _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
   _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
   }

Comment: Additionally, how would I use push_back for the other loop? I am having a hard time getting that to work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo! Unfortunately, still getting the same error when I run it :/

Comment: @Cool It might be other place causing the error. You might check the similar error in the code, or try to use debugger to figure out it.

Comment: I'll try to figure something out and will keep on working hard on it! Thank you so much for guiding me in the right direction.